# Finding the longest common suffix between two strings C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm fairly new to C++ and I can't seem to figure this out.

I get some weird output when running it. I am also trying to do this in the simplest way possible. How would I go about just printing the word in the suffix array and not all of the extra stuff. I have tried multiple ways to do this and they still show up.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){

        char word1[80];
        char word2[80];
        char suffix[80];

        cout << "Enter the first word: ";
        cin >> word1;

        cout << "Enter the first word: ";
        cin >> word1;

        int len1 = strlen(word1);
        int len2 = strlen(word2);

        while(len1 > 0 && len2 > 0 && word1[len1] == word2[len2]) {
            int k=0;
            suffix[k]=word1[len1];  

            k++;
            len1--;
            len2--;
        }



        for(int i=strlen(suffix);i>=0; i--){
            cout << suffix[i];
        }



        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You never read in `word2`, you just read into `word1` twice. Also, you call `strlen` on `suffix`, but `suffix` is not a string. `word1` is a string because `cin >> word1;` reads in a string, but `suffix` is just an array of characters. (Think about it. How could `strlen` possibly know what to return?)

Comment: word2 is used in the while loop, if they are the same then it really doesn't matter that I use word1's values. I've also tried to replace the strlen(suffix) with k after removing it from the while local but that didn't work ethier                *****sorry about that I see what you meant by the word1 thing now, my mistake.

Comment: Problem lies here:

`word1[len1] == word2[len2]` you want `word1[len1-1] == word2[len2-1]`

Comment: Other problem `int k=0;` is inside your loop. You're only ever modifying `suffix[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

- You should better use `string` instead of an array of `char`. That way,
  you don't have to worry about memory.
- The line int `k=0;` should be outside of the `while`.
- Remember that arrays start at 0, so substract 1 from the length of
  the words and iterate while`len1 >= 0 && len2 >= 0`
- Using strings, you can use the method `substr` (reference
  [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)).

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word1,word2,suffix;
    cout << "Enter the first word: ";
    cin >> word1;
    cout << "Enter the first word: ";
    cin >> word2;
    int len1 = word1.size()-1;
    int len2 = word2.size()-1;
    int k=0;
    while(len1 >= 0 && len2 >= 0 && word1[len1] == word2[len2]) {
        len1--;
        len2--;
        k++;
    }
    suffix=word1.substr(word1.size()-k,k);
    cout << suffix;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am getting a string subscript out of range error on this code coming from the suffix= section

Comment: @user2924136 I can't replicate that error. On which input did you get it?

Comment: Nevermind I had acidentally looked over the -1 in the part where you had declared the len variables

Answer (score 1):

I always think the "simplest way possible" is to use someone else's work. Here
is one way to write your program that leverages the standard library:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string suffix(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
    size_t len = std::min(a.size(), b.size());
    auto its = std::mismatch(a.rbegin(), a.rbegin()+len, b.rbegin());
    return std::string(its.first.base(), a.end());

}

int main () {
    std::cout << suffix("December", "May") << "\n";
    std::cout << suffix("January", "February") << "\n";
    std::cout << suffix("April", "April") << "\n";
}
```